# Python 2d array

Tags: python

I want to make 2D array, which is 50X75.
Computer has to make random coordinates inside the array, about 15 to 20 coordinates. 
What should I do TT
I stopped with the first step, making 50X75 2D array, so help meTT

Comment: Kindly mark the best answer

Answer (score 0):

You can generate 2D array using random runmbers

```
from random import randint
coordinates = [[randint(1, 100), randint(1, 100)] for i in range(20)]
```

> Output: [[81, 52], [12, 79], [24, 90], [93, 53], [98, 17], [40, 44], [31, 1], [1, 40], [8, 34], [81, 31], [87, 50], [45, 72], [86, 70], [43, 78], [64, 80], [85, 76], [28, 43], [81, 78], [80, 55], [82, 58]]

Comment: what  if I want to make a normal 2D array list? for example,
[0,0] [0,1] [0,2].....
[1,0]....
like this, in 50X75 2d array

Comment: It's a 2D array in above answer. You can't carry on your inner 2 items lists without a container / list

Answer (score 0):

A 50 x 75 2D array can be made using a np.reshape function. Here is an example, hope this helps.

```
import numpy as np
np.arange(3750).reshape(50, 75) # the array has 50 rows and 75 cols

array([[   0,    1,    2, ...,   72,   73,   74],
   [  75,   76,   77, ...,  147,  148,  149],
   [ 150,  151,  152, ...,  222,  223,  224],
   ..., 
   [3525, 3526, 3527, ..., 3597, 3598, 3599],
   [3600, 3601, 3602, ..., 3672, 3673, 3674],
   [3675, 3676, 3677, ..., 3747, 3748, 3749]])
```

Comment: sorry, but I didn't learn about numpy and how to install..TT Is there another way without using numpy?